# django-admin.py startproject mysite isn't working

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows, powershell

`admin.py startproject mysite` before and it worked fine but now when I try to use it nothing happens I've tried solutions from the other articles on this but none of them worked. Please help I keep getting this error

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"g:\python\python.exe" "G:\Python\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject mysite'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future, please link the other solutions that you have tried, and also the error that you are specifically getting.

If you are doing what I think you're doing, which is running `django-admin.py startproject mysite`, then this will not work because you are trying to call a file that doesn't exist. If you want to start a Django project you have to run `django-admin startproject mysite`. Notice how there's no `.py` after `django-admin`. You can read more in the Django tutorial site: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/.

Comment: Ok I tried that solution and got this error: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"g:\python\python.exe"  "G:\Python\Scripts\django-admin.exe" startproject mysite'

Answer (score 0):

Theres seems to be a small bug in that your path as 2 quotation marks ('") in  '"g:\python\python.exe". Since you are a begginer Id say for you to try and unninstall python and install again the newest version availeable at the official website.

A similar issue for you to look into if it doesnt work: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5223